# Convert a massive (20mb+) single-line JSON file into a multi-line file

Tags: json

I have a huge one line json file that I want to convert into a multi-line file so I can read it. I have tried to use online tools but unsurprisingly they just crash. I have looked at python scrips but they haven't worked. I do have a Linux machine but it only has very minimal ram (2GB) and so I doubt if they load the file into ram that it would work.

Comment: You could load it into a Python script with `json.load()` and dump it back to a file with `json.dump(open("pretty.json", w), indent=4)`.

Comment: I think [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) doesn't load the entire file into memory to prettyprint it.

Comment: Questions asking for suggestions are [off topic on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). However, have you tried VS Code? It's pretty resource efficient and can format JSON files out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

In which "multi-line-file" do you want to convert it to?
If you want it as a JSON but parsed you can use

```
JSON.parse(<stringified json>)
```

if you are in vscode you can also try different extensions for pretty format if you mean that format what i think of.

Comment: With "very minimal RAM", this will likely not work because it requires the entire file to be read into memory.

Comment: Which size do we talk about with "minimal ram"?

Comment: 2GB of ram @Jubewe

Comment: Oh ok yea i cant help you then i thought about maybe 8gb